# Weapon scaling in "One Tamriel" update 14 (and onwards) regarding leveling?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

Ì noticed that if I had a level 48 sword, and was level 48, it did X amount of damage.

Once I leveled up to level 49, it did Y amount of damage, where Y was less than X.

My guess is that the actual damage output of a weapon is also dependent on the level difference between the item and your level.

This has held true also through champion levels but I see mention of 160 being one sort of cap and 561 another.

My question is this, is my understanding which I will write out below correct?

- Weapon output is indeed *also* dependant on the level difference between the item and your own level, leveling above the item level will decrease its damage output (and this also seems to hold true for armor, decrease its armor or other bonuses).
- This is also true upwards through champion points from level 50
- **However**, once at 160, everything stops scaling. Weapons stop "downgrading" once I reach 170, 180, etc.

The last point is the important one. Is the above true?

I'm on console, Xbox One, but I don't think this matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your items won't get any stronger once you hit Champion 160 (except from additional passive Champion points invested in passive abilities of course) and they scale below that level based on your own character level.

So a Champion 160 character with a Champion 150 weapon should indeed be weaker than a Champion 150 character with a Champion 150 weapon.

This scaling will stop with Champion 160 for obvious reasons since it's the maximum item level right now. So once you're using Champion 160 items, they'll no longer scale worse no matter your increasing champion level.

Comment: But what about a champion 160 weapon and me being champion points 170, then 180, 190, etc. ? Will the gear get progressively worse the same way as a level 45 item got progressively worse as I became 46, then 47, then 48, etc.? Or will the different no longer impact the weapon at 160?

Comment: In other words, you confirm that 160 character with 150 gear will be weaker than a 150 character with 150 gear, so my question is what about a 170 character with 160 gear, will the "weakening" part stop at 160?

Comment: It will stop, because CP160 is the current maximum regarding raw character power/equipment. Above that only progression left are champion passives.

Comment: OK, nice, thanks, please edit this last part into your answer so that the answer is complete without the comments.